# Scraping Google Scholar, article title

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to create a list of articles for a study using Google Scholar (among others), and I get several thousands of results. Copy pasting these manually will take forever....

I wrote the following code for BeautifulSoup (I'm a noob) but I get no output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSou`p

article_info = []
pages = np.arange(1,1770,10) # Since I got 17 700 results, and there are 10 articles per page


for page in pages:
    page = requests.get("https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=" + str(pages) + "&q=mitochondrial+synthesis&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&as_ylo=2020&as_yhi=2022&as_rr=1")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    article_names = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'gs_r gs_or gs_scl'})
    for store in article_names:
        name = store.h3.a.text
        article_info.append(name)`

article_list = pd.DataFrame({'Article name': article_info})
article_list
```

I think all article names (text) are in a div called "gs_r gs_or gs_scl", which holds an H3 , which holds an "a" tag.

[Google Scholar HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzKbH.png)

But I get no output....
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3LHi.png)

Grateful for any advice.
Thanks and best regards,

Comment: Have you checked that the divs actually exist in the returned HTML? Google doesn't like scripted bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than np.arange, try the range function to set the first and last page number for your URLs. I added a time.sleep() call to slow down the requests. You can try different values to test the tolerance of the server. You will get HTTP 429 responses if not. I don't know if you truly need a data frame, but I also added the option to write the DF to a CSV file. The CSV will have two columns, the first is the article title and the second is the URL.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

article_info = []

# range(first_page, last_page)
for i in range(1, 20):
    page = requests.get("https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=" + str(i) + "&q=mitochondrial+synthesis&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&as_ylo=2020&as_yhi=2022&as_rr=1")
    # http status code
    print(page)
    # sleep between requests
    time.sleep(60)
     
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    article_names = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'gs_r gs_or gs_scl'})
    for store in article_names:
        title = store.h3.a.text
        url = store.h3.a
        article_info.append([title, url['href']])

article_list = pd.DataFrame(article_info)

# write to CSV
article_list.to_csv('scholar_titles.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
Mechanisms and regulation of protein synthesis in mitochondria   | https://www.nature.com/articles/s41580-021-00332-2
Mitochondrial OXPHOS biogenesis: Co-regulation of protein synthesis, import, and assembly pathways | https://www.mdpi.com/1422-0067/21/11/3820/pdf?version=1591105531
...
```

Comment: Hi Captain Caveman, thanks a lot for your response!
However, I keep getting [429] even though I have changed the time.sleep to e.g. 10.
Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Are you getting any 200 responses and then 429? The code works. I was able to download 100 pages.

Comment: Also, I think the code should be
'..../scholar?start=" + str(i) + "0&q=mitoc..... ' , with a 0 after  +" , since Google Scholar pages start from 0 (or 00) and then 10, 20, 30 etc.

Comment: I belive you that it works! But I don't get any 200 responses at all :D

Comment: I think it works now. I get a bunch of 200 responses. Will wait until the loop is done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: nice! happy to hear it. Make sure you add a delay or you will get blocked.